# How can I parallelize np.matmul and np.multiply?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a question about matrix calculation using numpy. How can I parallelize these calculation such as `np.matmul` and `np.multiply`? I cannot find any references describing how to compute np.matmul using parallelization.

```
def time_shift_R(V, R_1, I0, t): # V is the potential function which returns an array
    temp1 = V(xx, yy, t) + B*I0**2 
    temp = P*np.matmul(M, I0) + Q*np.matmul(I0, M) - np.multiply(temp1, I0)
    R1 = ( R_1 - dt*temp ) / ( 1 - dt*B*R_1*I0 ) 
    return R1
```

I appreciate your kind help in advance.

Comment: It's (matmul; i wouldn't care about multiply) already parallelized (in a state of the art way) if you obtained a numpy distributed with a BLAS backend (which is usually the case). At least if we are talking about float or double types here.

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your reply. I want to make my code faster, but I cannot find any proper method to speed it up. Parallelization may be one way, but I would like to apply other methods if they make my code faster.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing something about the variables, such as the shape and dtype of the arrays,  And whether/how you call this function repeatedly.  While we can assume `IO` and `M` are arrays (2d?) because otherwise they wouldn't work in `matmul`, we don't know about the other variables.  Why use `np.multiply` instead of `temp1*IO`?  You use a lot of `*` already.

Comment: Not all BLAS implementations are parallel and this can be one of the problem. Make sure you use a proper BLAS implementation. Good ones includes OpenBLAS, BLIS and the MKL.

Comment: @hpaulj V, I0, R_1, M are matrices whose data type is complex, and B, dt are constants whose data type is float. Since I recognize that np.multiply is faster than *, I used np.multiply.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Thank you for good suggestion. Maybe I could use other method such as scipy.linalg rather than ```np.matmul```.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do some time tests to see what exactly is taking most time.  For example on a rather modest machine with stock Ubuntu linux:

Make a complex array (you didn't cite any sizes so I'm just guessing as to something reasonable):

```
In [60]: A = np.ones((1000,1000),complex)
```

`multiply` and the operator * are basically the same:

```
In [61]: timeit A*A
7.49 ms ± 4.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [62]: timeit np.multiply(A,A)
7.48 ms ± 6.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`matmul` is quite a bit longer, but then it's doing a lot more.  A faster BLAS equivalent might help here.  Note `matmul` is smart enough to use a specialized BLAS function for the transpose case.  The @ operator is basically the same.

```
In [63]: timeit np.matmul(A,A)
381 ms ± 8.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [64]: timeit np.matmul(A,A.T)
231 ms ± 9.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and the power calc:

```
In [65]: timeit 10.0*A**2
14.4 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The `V(xx, yy, t)` is unknown.